# file content comparison issue c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ienumerable

my requirement is to move files from one directory to another after certain interval. So basic copy works, but during the next subsequent interval I want to move only the new files.

Following is my approach:

I am creating the file list of both source & target directory in target location, the idea is based on the difference of these two files copy only the files that are new from last iteration.

For 1st iteration it will create a blank file in target indicating copy everything. But my file comparison is hitting issues here, based on logic in below code it's creating this excpetion "System.Linq.Enumerable+d__99`1[System.String]"

Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    create_source_fileList();
    string source_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir"];

    string target_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir"];

    string dpath = target_dir + "Diff" + ".txt";

    TextWriter df = new StreamWriter(dpath);

    DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(source_dir);

    DirectoryInfo targetinfo = new DirectoryInfo(target_dir);

    string[] source_f_list  = File.ReadAllLines(target_dir + "Source_File_List.txt");
    string[] target_f_list = File.ReadAllLines(target_dir + "Target_File_List.txt");

    IEnumerable<String> file_list_diff = source_f_list.Except(target_f_list);


    df.WriteLine(file_list_diff);
    df.Close();


    if (!Directory.Exists(targetinfo.FullName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetinfo.FullName);
    }
    foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
    {

            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetinfo.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
    }

    create_target_fileList();

}
```

Need help in fixing this issue,also will this approach down the line work in loop where I will iterate only the names in diff file.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not creating an exception; rather, it's writing the result of calling `ToString` on an `IEnumerable<string>` instance. You need to replace:

```
df.WriteLine(file_list_diff);
```

with

```
df.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, file_list_diff));
```

or, prior to .NET 4:

```
df.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, file_list_diff.ToArray()));
```